# Trying to create an accordion menu and when I click on the title of the question, the answer doesn't appear or collapse, why is this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an accordion  menu that allows me to make my answers hidden and only appear at the click of the question. For some reason when you click on the question nothing happens.

my code:

```css
.accordion-Section {
  background: #fdfdfd;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10vh 0 0;
}

.accordion-Title {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1;
}

.accordion-Title h2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #E91E63;
  bottom: -25px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.accordion-Title p {
  padding: 0 190px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.faq {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 48px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.faq .accordion {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #CEE1F8;
}

.faq .card .accordionCardHeader {
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.faq .card .accordionCardHeader:hover {
  background: rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.1);
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.faq .card .accordionCardHeader .accordion-Title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #3B566E;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.faq .card .accordionCardHeader .accordion-Title .badge {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 14px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E91E63;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.faq .card .card-body {
  padding: 30px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #6F8BA4;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #F3F8FF;
}

.faq .card .card-body p {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .faq {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .faq .card .accordionCardHeader .accordion-Title {
    line-height: 26px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>

  <section class="accordian-Section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <div class="accordion-Title text-center pb-3">
            <h2> About </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <div class="faq" id="accordion">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="accordionCardHeader" id="accordionHeading-1">
                <div class="mb-0">
                  <h5 class="accordion-Title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="accordionCollapse-1" data-area-expanded="true" data-aria-controls="accordionCollapse-1">
                    <span class="badge">1</span> What is Lorem Ipsum? </h5>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="accordionCollapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="accordionHeading-1" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                    book. </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
  <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
</body>
```

Expected: Accordion menu should appear and collapse when you click the question.

Actual: When you click on the question nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare the `data-target` it has to be a normal CSS selector, so change `data-target="accordionCollapse-1"` to `data-target="#accordionCollapse-1"` since you try to open a `div` that has an `id` attribute.

Refer to [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) for more info!

```css
.accordion-Section {
  background: #fdfdfd;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10vh 0 0;
}

.accordion-Title {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1;
}

.accordion-Title h2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #E91E63;
  bottom: -25px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.accordion-Title p {
  padding: 0 190px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.faq {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 48px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.faq .accordion {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #CEE1F8;
}

.faq .card .accordionCardHeader {
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.faq .card .accordionCardHeader:hover {
  background: rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.1);
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.faq .card .accordionCardHeader .accordion-Title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #3B566E;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.faq .card .accordionCardHeader .accordion-Title .badge {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 14px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E91E63;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.faq .card .card-body {
  padding: 30px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #6F8BA4;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #F3F8FF;
}

.faq .card .card-body p {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .faq {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .faq .card .accordionCardHeader .accordion-Title {
    line-height: 26px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <section class="accordian-Section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <div class="accordion-Title text-center pb-3">
            <h2> About </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <div class="faq" id="accordion">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="accordionCardHeader" id="accordionHeading-1">
                <div class="mb-0">
                  <h5 class="accordion-Title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordionCollapse-1" data-area-expanded="true" data-aria-controls="accordionCollapse-1">
                    <span class="badge">1</span> What is Lorem Ipsum? </h5>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="accordionCollapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="accordionHeading-1" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                    book. </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
```

Also, at this moment the `data-target` is set to the `h5` tag and not the surrounding container. To fix this you have to remove the following attributes of your `h5` tag and add them to your `div` with the `id="accordionHeading-1"`:

- `data-target="#accordionCollapse-1"`
- `data-area-expanded="true"`
- `data-aria-controls="accordionCollapse-1"`

I also added CSS to give the box a `pointer` cursor:

```
.accordionCardHeader {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```css
.accordionCardHeader {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-Section {
  background: #fdfdfd;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10vh 0 0;
}

.accordion-Title {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1;
}

.accordion-Title h2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #E91E63;
  bottom: -25px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.accordion-Title p {
  padding: 0 190px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.faq {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 48px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.faq .accordion {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #CEE1F8;
}

.faq .card .accordionCardHeader {
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.faq .card .accordionCardHeader:hover {
  background: rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.1);
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.faq .card .accordionCardHeader .accordion-Title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #3B566E;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.faq .card .accordionCardHeader .accordion-Title .badge {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 14px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E91E63;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.faq .card .card-body {
  padding: 30px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #6F8BA4;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #F3F8FF;
}

.faq .card .card-body p {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .faq {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .faq .card .accordionCardHeader .accordion-Title {
    line-height: 26px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="accordian-Section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <div class="accordion-Title text-center pb-3">
          <h2> About </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <div class="faq" id="accordion">
          <div class="card">
            <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordionCollapse-1" data-area-expanded="true" data-aria-controls="accordionCollapse-1" class="accordionCardHeader" id="accordionHeading-1">
              <div class="mb-0">
                <h5 class="accordion-Title">
                  <span class="badge">1</span> What is Lorem Ipsum? </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="accordionCollapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="accordionHeading-1" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                  book. </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Is the only change I need to make to change the data-target and add the #accordionCollapse-1 correct? and since the data-target is set to the h1 tag and not the container around it, how can I fix this?

Comment: "Is the only change I need to make to change the data-target and add the #accordionCollapse-1 correct?" If you want to click on the `h1` tag to open it, yes. "since the data-target is set to the h1 tag and not the container around it, how can I fix this?" will do an edit in a couple of minutes, be advised.

Comment: I would prefer to have the menu collapse when you click on the box, not just the header! and okay will be waiting for edits, thank you for your time.

Comment: thank you so much, this helped a lot. With this change I can now click into the box anywhere and it collapses.

Comment: would you possibly know what part in the code is making the size of the menu responsive?

Comment: The CSS of `.container` that is predefined by Bootstrap. They add an `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` which centers the container. They then give him a `padding` so there is always `15px` space to the left and right. Furthermore, they add a `width: 100%` but limit it with `max-width`. But this is all basic CSS knowledge. If you have to ask questions like this imo Bootstrap isn't the way to go for you now. Learn the basics then you can take a look at frameworks and more complex stuff.

Comment: Alright I will keep that in mind, but do you know what specifically makes the height so responsive?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "responsive height"?! The height is static.

Comment: Okay... im a little confused lol! going to have to study this

Comment: If you mean the scroll-up/-down effect, this is JavaScript.